# Django. Вывод информации из обновляемого json-файла

Tags: python, django, json

В моём Django-проекте есть одна БД, информация из которой выводится на страницу в табличном виде.
Также есть источник, откуда скачивается json-файл с дополнительной информацией по элементам БД. Имена элементов в БД и json идентичны.

Что мне необходимо реализовать: чтобы после загрузки страницы пользователь видел в одной таблице информацию из БД, дополненную каким-то образом информацией из json-файла, ориентируясь по имени элементов.

Не надо, чтобы информация обновлялась на странице в реальном времени. Достаточно, чтобы несколько раз в час приложение загружало новую версию json-файла и уже после обновления страницы пользователь видел актуальную версию той части данных, которая берётся из json.

Как это было бы проще всего реализовать?

Comment: Можете создать `management command` которая будет сохранять в кеш для нужного объекта информацию из `json` файла и храните еще, например чуть больше часа. Ставите команду в крон на каждый час, и пусть она обновляет кеш каждый час. Или тоже самое но + работа в реальном времени и тот же кеш, но уже можно прямо в шаблоне и без `management command`

Comment: Еще можно в `celery` реализовать таск который с каким то интервалом будет обновлять эту информацию в кэше.